# Connecting Multiple Android VMs via Bluetooth

Tags: android, android-emulator, bluetooth, vmware-workstation

I was trying to run androidx86-ieee.iso on VM and everything works fine. The VMs (Android) can connect to the internet via bridge mode successfuly, share Bluetooth via my dongle on Windows 7 host (since no error is thrown while activating Bluetooh). But the devices cannot detect each other (or my phone for that matter).

I recall in the previous VMWare version (v7) when there was no support to share Bluetooth device, I could connect to my phone when only 1 of the VM had control over it (Sharing Bluetooth was not permitted). But I required Bluetooth sharing.

My netcfg shows 192.168.1.x address for both devices since they are connected to the internet, but cannot see each other on bluetooth.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. I googled aplenty and found out the 2.3 Gingerbread android x86 iso  I was using is buggy as confirmed by a user here [Android-x86 Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-x86/qFlDxTo9VGk) and had requested him for the ISO he compiled after fixing the Android 2.3 code, which he rightfully obliged.

For anyone viewing this or having the same problem, the fixed ISO is uploaded [here](https://sites.google.com/site/androbox73/download).